# R different colours for set of bars in barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, plotly

How do I have different colours for specific bars of a bar chart in R ? Specific set of bars change dynamically.

[image]

The logic behind is, I have to find out the last 3 months of the data and apply different colours for those bars, in addition to that, I have to apply the same colour to those months in previous years.

Lets say, now it is May 2017, so last 3 months are Feb,Mar,Apr. So I have to apply different colours only for those months every year in the chart.

I am trying to use plotly or highcharts through r here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, the problem you have is the creation of the color vector, not the choice of the plotting package.  I go through two different approaches below. The  first is more manual, the second is a little more automated, but assumes you are running the code in the month after you want to highlight the previous 3 months for the report. However, both should illustrate ways that you can customize it for your own use.

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(date=c(rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),2),c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr")),
                   plotdata=(abs(rep(rnorm(28)*100))))
###this is manual and requires customization based on your data set ###    
mycol <- rep(4,nrow(data)) ## setting color vector to blue by default (value = 4)
mycol[c(length(mycol),length(mycol)-1,length(mycol)-2,
        length(mycol)-12,length(mycol)-13,length(mycol)-14,
        length(mycol)-24,length(mycol)-25,length(mycol)-26)] <- 2
barplot(data$plotdata,col=mycol)

###Second Way: Define past 3 months from current month. Lubridate allows
### for easy date calculations as shown below.

past3months <- c(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(1),"month"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(2),"month"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(3),"month"))
past3months <- format(past3months,"%b") ### changing the date format to match the data ####
data$mycol2 <- ifelse(data$date %in% past3months,2,4)

barplot(data$plotdata,col=data$mycol2)
```

Both pieces of code will generate the following graph (made with base graphics)
[image]